# Django: Flaky file downloads

Tags: django

I've made a simple file server that runs on my raspberry pi (1/2 gb RAM, 1 CPU). It's running under gunicorn (3 workers) behind nginx (1 worker).

I've got a weird issue where when I try to download too many files simultaneously (say 5) they all get part way through and then just abort. There's no output from the django server (I get this issue using the development server too which is why it's now running behind gunicorn & nginx, but still no joy).

My download view is:

```
@never_cache
def download_media(request, user_id, session_key, id, filepath):
    "Download an individual media file"

    context = RequestContext(request)

    # validate the user_id & session_key pair
    if not __validate_session_key(user_id, session_key):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('handle_logout'))

    filepath = unicode(urllib.unquote(filepath))

    if '..' in filepath:
        raise SuspiciousOperation('Invalid characters in subdir parameter.')

    location = MediaCollectionLocation.objects.get(id=id)

    path = os.path.join(location.path, filepath)

    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file(path)), content_type='application/octet-stream')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(path)

    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path)
    response["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    return response
```

I'm serving files this way because I want clients to authenticate (so don't just want to redirect and serve static content with nginx).

Anyone any idea why it'd drop out if I make several requests in parallel?

Comment: have you tried running this script on another linux machine (i.e. not on your raspberry pi - presumably running raspbian)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why the files would be failing, but I'd imagine it'd have something to do with downloading more files than you have workers, or that there is a timeout happening between nginx and gunicorn.

You can get nginx to serve the files only after django has authenticated the user by making django set a particular header that nginx then reads (internal only) and serves the file itself.

[XSendFile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) is what nginx uses to do this. You may then either create some middleware or a function to set the appropriate headers from django, or use something like [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) with the nginx backend to have it all done for you.

If the issue you're experiencing is caused by a timeout between django and nginx, this fix should solve it. If it does not, increase the number of nginx workers as well, since it will be responsible for the serving of files now.